# Передача данных из одной таблицы в другую (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Возможно ли передать сгруппированные данные из временнной таблицы в основную посредством запросов в БД без дополнительных выгрузок и инсертов соответственно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2)
select col1, max(col2) from table1 group by col1;
```

Не забываем, что колонки в `select`'е должны быть перечислены в том же порядке, что и в `insert`'е и иметь те же типы.

Comment: Хм... спасисбо А на как это скажется на производительности, если скажем таких инсертов будет от 5000? Возможно ли передавать пуллами около 1мб?

Comment: Чего не знаю, того не знаю. В MySQL имеются серьёзные проблемы с производительностью в подзапросах в `select`. При выборке с подзапросом MySQL вычисляет подзапрос для каждой записи основного запроса, что очень сильно тормозит выборку. Вроде это пофиксали в 6 версии, но не до конца. Насчёт `insert`'ов не уверен.